# Map parent to Child with different column names JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Springboot 2.5.2 with JPA
I am trying to map a parent child table but they have different names in the actual DB.
My parent Entity class looks ass follows

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="PARENTTABLE")
public class ParentEntity implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8610605997974967804L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PID")
    private int pId;
    @Column(name = "COL_ID_0")
    private String colId_0;
    @Column(name = "DATA1")
    private String data1_0;
    @Column(name = "DATA2")
    private String data2_0;
        
    //Joining Entity/Table
     @OneToMany(targetEntity = ChildEntity.class,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     @JoinColumn(name = "COL_IDD",
            referencedColumnName = "COL_ID_0")
     private List<ChildEntity> childenity;
     // ..getters and Setters
```

and my Child Entity/Table

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="CHILDRENTABLE")
public class ChildEntity implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2781104466439391315L;
    @Id
    @Column(name="CID")
    private int cId;
    @Column(name="COL_IDD")
    private String colIdd;
    @Column(name = "DETIALS1")
    private String datai1_1;
    @Column(name = "DETIALS2")
    private String datai1_2;
        
    // ..getters and setters
```

How do you link these two entity classes with each other to display the Parent and details?
With the above configurations I get the Parent data back but the child records does not display only containing `null` in the Api call.

@JensSchauder Sorry meant to say the endpoint from the controller class. The database is exactly setup as the above example (not the real names) the Parent class contains the header data and the child class contains the details of the parent.
I need to call the end point for the parent entity and then it should list the child data along with it. as per the below example
JSON result I am expecting

```
'[
    {
        "pId": 2,
        "colId_0": "5555",
        "data1_0": "6001363000007",
        "data2_0": "6001001392709",
        "childenity": [{"cId": 222,
                        "colIdd": "5555",
                        "datai1_1": "Data222",
                        "datai1_2": "Data222"
                       },
                       {"cId": 333,
                        "colIdd": "5555",
                        "datai1_1": "Data333",
                        "datai1_2": "Data333"
                       }
                      ]
     }
]'
```

But I get the following

```
[
    {
        "pId": 2,
        "colId_0": "5555",
        "data1_0": "6001363000007",
        "data2_0": "6001001392709",
        "childenity": "null"
     }
]
```

Comment: What API call are you talking about? So far you have only shown us two entity classes which indeed are "linked"? What query are you executing? What data is in the database?

Comment: I have the idea that the join is in reverse. It should be `@JoinColumn(name = "COL_ID_0", referencedColumnName = "COL_IDD")` I think. But that is also for a large part guesswork, it's hard to reason about these things without being able to see the database structure.

Comment: So what is constructing this JSON? And how have you tested that the data you describe is actually in the database?

Comment: @JensSchauder I have narrowed it down that it has to be a joining issue.
I have a controller class for both the parent and children and if I call them separately they return the data. The Json is getting created from the controller class where the  produces type is APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE.
It is only when I call the parent table that has the details linked in it the header data comes back but the details are null.

Comment: I have checked and the Rest class does have the list<Children> in them.

After debugging the call I get the following issue "Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException' exception."

I am not sure how further to investigate to see the issue a s the show SQL is activated in the applications.prop file and the SQL only returns the parent table select.

Comment: We won't be able to help as long as you don't show as the relevant code.